# show toString on JSON element using JAXB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, jaxb

I start to study java + mongodb, so I start to do a restfull, all its works, but there is one attribute on my Cliente class, what I'd like to customize his deserialization, "the private ObjectId id", this is my class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Cliente {

    private ObjectId id;
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String rg;

    //methods…

}
```

when I do deserialization I get This:

```
{
    "id": {
        "timestamp": 1537705891,
        "machineIdentifier": 13207740,
        "processIdentifier": -17673,
        "counter": 3768415,
        "time": 1537705891000,
        "date": 1537705891000,
        "timeSecond": 1537705891
    },
    "nome": "Kathia",
    "cpf": "470.428.859-53",
    "rg": "25.876.962-8"
}
```

But I like to get this:

```
{
    "id": "ObjectId('5ba7fdf1c988bcbaf7398060')";
    "nome": "Kathia",
    "cpf": "470.428.859-53",
    "rg": "25.876.962-8"
}
```

or

```
{
    "id": "5ba7fdf1c988bcbaf7398060";
    "nome": "Kathia",
    "cpf": "470.428.859-53",
    "rg": "25.876.962-8"
}
```

someone could help me, plz?

Comment: In your JSON examples it should be `,` instead of `;`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is handled by Jackson
then you can equip the `ObjectId id` property of your `Cliente` class
with a custom JSON serializer and deserializer
by annotating it with [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) and [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html).

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ObjectIdSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = ObjectIdDeserializer.class)
private ObjectId id;
```

Your serializer converts an `ObjectId` instance to a String like e.g.
`"ObjectId('5ba7fdf1c988bcbaf7398060')"` by means of the [`ObjectId.toHexString()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toHexString--) or [`ObjectId.toString()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#toString--) method:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class ObjectIdSerializer extends StdSerializer<ObjectId> {

    public ObjectIdSerializer() {
        super(ObjectId.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(ObjectId value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString("ObjectId('" + value.toString() + "')");
    }
 }
```

Likewise your deserializer converts a String like e.g.
`"ObjectId('5ba7fdf1c988bcbaf7398060')"` to an `ObjectId` instance
by means of the [`ObjectId(String hexString)`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html#ObjectId-java.lang.String-) constructor.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

public class ObjectIdDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ObjectId> {

    public ObjectIdDeserializer() {
        super(ObjectId.class);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectId deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String s = parser.getValueAsString();
        try {
            String[] parts = s.split("'");
            String hexString = parts[1]; // get the part between 1st ' and 2nd '
            return new ObjectId(hexString);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(parser, "parsing error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using jaxb.